# How do i get all the certifications assigned to a user in oim 12c using java api

Tags: java, oim

I have this function which gets the count of the certificates, but it gets all the certificates available in the instance, i want only the certificates assigned to the logged in user

```
    public long certificateCount(OIMClient oimclient) throws CertificationServiceException {
        CertificationService cs = oimclient.getService(CertificationService.class);

        SearchCriteria criteriaUserLogin = new SearchCriteria(UserManagerConstants.AttributeName.USER_LOGIN.getId(), "eiifnw", SearchCriteria.Operator.EQUAL);
        // System.out.println(cs.getUserCertificationStats(1L, "xelsysadm")); //this is straight up an error
        return cs.countCertifications(criteriaUserLogin);
    }
```

Also similarly how do i get information on every certificate, and the count of provisioned tasks and the pending approvals of an user in the instance.

TIA